# Vertically align image and textarea in a table cell

Tags: html, css

What I have:

```
        XXX
        XXX
Google  XXX
```

What I want:

```
       XXX
Google XXX
       XXX
```

What I tried:

```
<table border="4">
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: middle; height: 400px">
    <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="http://www.google.se/images/google_80wht.gif" alt="Google logo">
    <textarea style="height: 200px; display: inline-block"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Somehow, the image is not aligning vertically, even if I put a `vertical-align: middle` on the cell's style. The textarea instead aligns correctly in the center.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uydmjgby/

I cannot add any new column or row, the formatting must occour withing that cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `vertical-align: middle` on the textarea https://jsfiddle.net/uydmjgby/1/

Comment: It works! But why by default it's not aligning properly? Shouldn't `vertical-align: middle` of the cell already work on the image and textarea? Why it's needed to do that on the textarea even if it was correctly centered before?

Comment: I wish I had the answers @Bob, I was as surprised as you :)